# Eclipse Hadoop plugin issue(Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:50070 )Can any body give me the solution for this?

Tags: hadoop, eclipse-plugin, hdfs

Issue: Eclipse Hadoop plugin issue(Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:50070 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException). Can any body give me the solution for this?

I am having Cloudera training tutorial. Which uses Eclipse(Helios)3.6 and Hadoop.0.20.2-cdh3u2 versions.

I had downloaded the hadoop-eclipse-plugin-0.20.3-SNAPSHOT.jar and copied the same in /home/training/eclipse/plugins/ folder.

```
Run --> Eclipse --> gone to File (which is in Menu bar) --> New --> other
```

From other Selected the MapReduce Project. I had selected the Specify Hadoop library location. And given location as "/usr/lib/hadoop".
In this location I have below files.

```
bin                                hadoop-examples-0.20.2-cdh3u2.jar
build.xml                          hadoop-examples.jar
CHANGES.txt                        hadoop-test-0.20.2-cdh3u2.jar
conf                               hadoop-test.jar
contrib                            hadoop-tools-0.20.2-cdh3u2.jar
example-confs                      hadoop-tools.jar
hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u2-ant.jar       ivy
hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u2-core.jar      ivy.xml
hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u2-examples.jar  lib
hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u2-test.jar      LICENSE.txt
hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u2-tools.jar     logs
hadoop-ant-0.20.2-cdh3u2.jar       NOTICE.txt
hadoop-ant.jar                     pids
hadoop-core-0.20.2-cdh3u2.jar      README.txt
hadoop-core.jar                    webapps
```

and given the Mpareduce Project as "myhadoop" and clicked the finish button.
I got the Mapreduce button at DFS Locations button and but not its hirearchy.

Gone and checked my dfs and mapred ports.

My core-site.xml is

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:8020</value>
  </property>
```

my mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:8021</value>
  </property>
```

At Map ReTo Define Hadoop Location in eclipse I had given as below.

```
Map/Reduce Master
Host: localhost
port 50021

DFS Master:
Host :localhost
Port:50020
```

at the same I am select use M/R host.

I had ran cloudera's example wordcount program but it is giving me below issue.
Please give me solution I am trying from 2 days.,....

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:50070 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:226)
    at $Proxy0.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:384)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:180)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1514)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:1548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1530)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:111)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:183)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.addInputPath(FileInputFormat.java:368)
    at WordCount.main(WordCount.java:65)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveResponse(Client.java:815)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:724)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the name of your machine in the configuration from localhost to the hostname