# Hadoop plugin for hadoop with Connection refused error

Tags: hadoop

I am getting below error when I am trying to configure hadoop plugin in eclipse.

```
Error:call to localhost:54310 failed on connection exception:java.net.connectException:Connection refused:no further informaion
```

Hadoop version is 1.0.4

I have installed hadoop in Linux and I am running my Eclipse using Windows.
In the hadoop location window, I have tried with host as localhost and linux server.

```
MR Master: Host: localhost and port 54311
DFS Master: Host: localhost and port 54310

MR Master: Host: <Linux server name> and port 54311
DFS Master: Host: <Linux server name> and port 54310
```

In my mapred-site.xml I see this entry entry `localhost:54311`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is about programming questions (see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).  Perhaps the sister site ServerFault is more appropriate for this question?

Comment: Don, I checked the site rules and and i see the below topics..                                       --a specific programming problem
--a software algorithm
-- software tools commonly used by programmers
My question is related to the software tool. Hope this helps

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591777/eclipse-hadoop-plugin-issuecall-to-localhost-127-0-0-150070-can-any-body-give/13604899#13604899

Comment: Tariq, My issue is different from the one you have posted. Mine is connection related issues.

Comment: @RajeshNavduri you should use the linux hostname/ip address in your eclipse configuration on windows. In case you can 1. telnet to <linux-ip> <port> on windows and 2. localhost <port> on linux, the network is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

ConnectionRefused error is, you are trying to connect a directory which you dont have permission to read/write.

This may be caused by, a directory created another user(e.g. root) and your master machine is trying to read from/write to that directory.

It is more likely that you are trying to read an input from wrong place. Check your input directory if there is no problem with it, check your output directory