# Hadoop 0.20.2 plugin in eclipse juno is not working

Tags: eclipse, hadoop-plugins

I've downloaded Hadoop 0.20.2 and copied the jar from **D:\Hadoop-Environment\hadoop-0.20.2\contrib** into **../plugins** folder of eclipse. But I'm not able to get the the MapReduce pessepective in eclipse. Kindly give a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any error message?

Comment: @Tariq No error message. But if I put 0.18.3 plugin jar then I get MapReduce perspective.But, Since I'm using hadoop 0.20.2 for my single node setup, I'm not able to browse the dfs from eclipse.

Comment: Have you build it properly? The plugin which comes with the distribution lacks some necessary stuff. You might find this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591777/eclipse-hadoop-plugin-issuecall-to-localhost-127-0-0-150070-can-any-body-give/13604899#13604899

Comment: In 0.20.2/lib folder There are only two jars matching from your jars specified. They are : 1. commons-cli-1.2.jar 2. commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar. I went through the steps you've specified there and did re-jar of modified hadoop-eclipse-plugins but still I'm not getting MapReduce Perspective.

Comment: This is strange. You can try building the plugin by taking these jars form some newer release. Also, it's always better to use a newer release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the solution. I just download Hadoop-0.20.3-eclipse-plugin.jar from this link:
https://code.google.com/p/hadoop-eclipse-plugin/downloads/detail?name=hadoop-0.20.3-dev-eclipse-plugin.jar&can=2&q=. 
With this I was able to configure eclipse juno(4.2) easily on for hadoop-0.20.2.